# Remove required owner from task

Tags: acumatica

When creating a new task that is related to a case, Acumatica requires that an owner be assigned to this new task.  What do I need to do to remove this requirement?  I am using 18.210.0010.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Owner field validation is done in the **RowPersisting** event:

```
protected virtual void CRActivity_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = e.Row as CRActivity;
            if (row == null) return;

            if ((e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert || e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Update) && row.OwnerID == null && row.WorkgroupID == null)
            {
                var displayName = PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<CRActivity.ownerID>(Tasks.Cache);
                var exception = new PXSetPropertyException(ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, displayName);
                if (Tasks.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<CRActivity.ownerID>(row, null, exception))
                {
                    throw new PXRowPersistingException(typeof(CRActivity.ownerID).Name, null, ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, displayName);
                }
            }
        }
```

In this case, given that this is the only validation taking place in the event, you could override it so that the original event is not invoked:

```
public class CRTaskMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CRTaskMaint>
  {
    protected void CRActivity_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
      //if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
      //  InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e); //Original Event handler is not invoked
    }
  }
```

Keep in mind that this answer shows how to make the Owner field not required from a technical perspective. However, further effects of this change in Acumatica i.e. other pages, reports, etc.  should be considered.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for the answer.